# Can't find reference Tao.OpenGl and Tao.Platform.Windows in Add reference window in MSV C# 2010 Express Edtn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl, tao-framework

Downloaded and installed the Tao framework. But visual studio shows no clue about it. I thought it will find automatically. Does it have anything to do with GAC? Here is a snapshot:

[image: Tao]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the solution [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.100%29.aspx). Specially look this section: **To display an assembly in the Add Reference dialog box**

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sexy visual studio extension that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879/) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image: screenshot]